# MatrixSymbol substitution in sympy

Tags: matrix, sympy, substitution

I'm having issues substituting for MatrixSymbols in sympy. Here's a basic code example:

```
>>> import sympy as sy
>>> x, y = sy.symbols('x y')
>>> v = sy.MatrixSymbol('v', 2, 1)
>>> w = sy.MatrixSymbol('w', 2, 1)
>>> 2 + 3
5
>>> (x + y).subs({x: 2, y: 3})
5
>>> sy.Matrix([2,2]) + sy.Matrix([3,3])
Matrix([
[5],
[5]])
>>> (v + w).subs({v: sy.Matrix([2,2]), w: sy.Matrix([3,3])})
Matrix([
[2],
[2]]) + Matrix([
[3],
[3]])
>>> (v + w).subs({v: sy.Matrix([2,2]), w: sy.Matrix([3,3])}).evalf()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-25398137decd> in <module>()
----> 1 (v+w).subs({v: sy.Matrix([2,2]), w: sy.Matrix([3,3])}).evalf()

AttributeError: 'MatAdd' object has no attribute 'evalf'
```

I'd expect the MatrixSymbols `v` and `w` to behave like the scalar symbols `x` and `y`, but they do not.

Is there a way I can evaluate expressions like `v + w` by plugging in vectors for `v` and `w`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `as_explicit`, which is a method of a *matrix expression* that turns it into an *explicit matrix*.

```
(v + w).subs({v: sy.Matrix([2,2]), w: sy.Matrix([3,3])}).as_explicit()
```

is `Matrix([[5], [5]])`

Comment: Great, that worked, but now I'm wondering why `sy.Matrix([2,2]) + sy.Matrix([3,3])` returns an explicit matrix instead of a matrix expression.

Or maybe in other words, I'm confused about the rationale for giving different return types when substituting using `subs` versus when substituting using manual copy-paste.

Comment: A matrix expression is an expression with matrix symbols.  There are no matrix symbols in `sy.Matrix([2,2]) + sy.Matrix([3,3])`, only explicit matrices. So the result is an explicit matrix.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So maybe I still don't understand how `subs` works. I know that `v + w` is an expression with matrix symbols, but why is `(v + w).subs({v: sy.Matrix([2,2]), w: sy.Matrix([3,3])})` an expression with matrix symbols? It evaluates to `Matrix([
[2],
[2]]) + Matrix([
[3],
[3]])` which has no symbols.

Comment: It's an unfortunate consequence of matrix expressions having their own addition operator,  `MatAdd` (different from regular addition `Add`). Both print as `+` but work differently. Adding MatrixSymbol objects creates a MatAdd. Replacing the arguments of `MatAdd` we get a weird situation: a matrix expression without matrix symbols (which shouldn't happen ideally). It does not evaluate because it's a MatAdd and not Add. Try `sy.srepr(...)` on a SymPy expression to see what it _really_ is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `srepr`, that'll be useful next time I'm confused. And thanks for the explanation.